# How to create liferay-portal-src-6.1.1-ce-ga2 in Eclipse

Tags: java, jsf-2, liferay-6

This might sound a bit silly, but I want to create an **Eclipse project for liferay-portal-src-6.1.1-ce-ga2**. But I have no idea what type of project should I choose this to be under Eclipse. I actually want to make some changes in ThemeDisplay.java which is under 'portal-service' (path - C:/liferay-portal-src-6.1.1-ce-ga2/portal-service/) folder and re-create the portal-service jar. How am I supposed to achieve it?

Comment: What changes do you need on `ThemeDisplay` exactly? It is really not recommended to start patching internal Liferay JARs. Even the EXT plugin is not recommended if you don't have an extremely good reason for it.

Answer (score 0):

First, you can simply import liferay-portal-src-6.1.1-ce-ga2 in Eclipse, since it has .project file.

Second, to change ThemeDisplay.java it is better to use ext-plugin, since it allows to override Liferay core classes. You can read more about it [here](http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Ext+Plugin)